# How can I calculate the sum of database values

Tags: php, while-loop, sum

How can I calculate the sum of all the values from a field in a MySQL table using PHP? I think I need to use a `while` function, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Example:

```
SELECT SUM(`field`) as sum FROM `table`
```

Comment: `$evetything = "SELECT SUM('amount') as sum FROM 'projects'";
$calculate = mysql_query($evetything);
echo $calculate;`

Is this ok?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are returning your results as an array of values something like:

```
$sum = array_sum($result_set);
```

May work, however is it easier to use MySQL SUM functions as the previous answer states.